# ReactJS and XML

Tags: xml, reactjs, rss, cdata

I'm trying to make an RSS Reader using React. I'm encountering some RSS Feeds (http://www.economist.com/sections/economics/rss.xml) have elements enclosed in a CDATA section and include HTML markup. What is the 'React' way to handle this?

My understanding is that ordinarily, if you use regular javascript/jquery to parse an XML document, that you would just get the data and write it directly to the HTML document, something like

```
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML
=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes[0].data
```

But since React uses a virtual DOM you can't do that. If you try to do

```
import React from 'react'

const Component = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('description')[0].childNodes.data}</div>
  )
}

export default Component
```

would display the section as a string full of HTML tags.

I was wondering if there was a correct or preferred way to handle this. I'm aware of dangerouslysetInnerHTML but would prefer to avoid that if possible since React seems to discourage people from using it. Right now I'm messing around with DomParser and trying to extract specific tags from the CDATA string and I have to wonder if there is some better way that I just haven't been able to find through Google and reading documentation.

Answer (score 2):

dangerouslySetInnerHTML is the correct thing to use here. The name is really meant as a reminder to be careful rather than a deterrent to ever use it. As the React docs say (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml):

> In general, setting HTML from code is risky because it's easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting (XSS) attack. So, you can set HTML directly from React, but you have to type out dangerouslySetInnerHTML and pass an object with a __html key, to remind yourself that it's dangerous.

So you do need to be careful and protect against XSS attacks. This involves sanitizing any html passed to dangerouslySetInnerHtml. This is especially important for your use case, since you don't have control over the html that you are consuming. DOMPurify is a library that can help you with that: https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify.